# ienumerable , looping in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ienumerable, guid

I'm creating a page with multiple file uploader in MVC.

What I want to achieve is when I submit values the images uploaded should be named as `guid` and an incrementing `i` value, like `guid0` , `guid1`, `guid2`. I tried for loop but its saving only one image until loop ends . `i++` isn't working though.

My controller looks like this:

```
public ActionResult Home(SomeClass someclass, IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
    {
        var guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        someclass.filename = guid;
        int i = 0;
        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            if (file.ContentLength > 0)
             {
                var fileName = guid + "" + i + ".jpg";
                var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/admin/Upload"), fileName);
                file.SaveAs(path);
                i++;                         
             }
         }
         db.someclasses.Add(someclass);
         db.SaveChanges();                
         return RedirectToAction("Preview");
      }
```

And my view looks like this

```
<input type="file" name="files" id=1>
<input type="file" name="files" id=2>
```

**Update** : I'm receiving 11 files at the if loop but once they go through the loop there is only single image in the images folder named fdea36c3-545a-4e08-8af4-7fa6bd88bc6b0 . what i'm trying to achieve is all 11 images named as fdea36c3-545a-4e08-8af4-7fa6bd88bc6b0, fdea36c3-545a-4e08-8af4-7fa6bd88bc6b1,fdea36c3-545a-4e08-8af4-7fa6bd88bc6b2.....so on .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this way if you have multiple file controls on view.
you can even have Guid initialized  for each file and can ignore appending i to the name.

```
public class MultipleFilesForm
{
    public HttpPostedFileBase file1 {get;set;}

    public HttpPostedFileBase file2 {get;set;}
}
```

action method as

```
public ActionResult Home(MultipleFilesForm form)
{
        var guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        someclass.filename = guid;
        int i = 0;

    if(form.file1 != null)
    {
             var file = form.file1;
             if (file.ContentLength > 0)
             {
                var fileName = guid + i.ToString() + Path.GetExtension(file.FileName));
                var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/admin/Upload"), fileName);
                file.SaveAs(path);
                i++;                         
             }
    }
    if(form.file2 != null)
    {
        //handle file
    }

    ...
}
```

**[UPDATE]**
try this way

try this as well.

```
for (int i = 0; i < Request.Files.Count; i++)
        {
            var file = Request.Files[i];

            if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
            {
     var fileName = guid + i.ToString() + Path.GetExtension(file.FileName)); 

var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/admin/Upload"), fileName);

 file.SaveAs(path); 

i++; 
            }
         }
```

Comment: i dont want to do this for each file, since its the 11 different images i need to set in and retrieve from database. thanks for the answer....

Comment: are you sure files from multiple file upload controls are available with IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files ? AFAIK, this gets multiple files only when file control is set with multiple attribute.

Comment: i'm receiving 11 files at file.contenLength >0 i there any way i can achieve fdea36c3-545a-4e08-8af4-7fa6bd88bc6b0,fdea36c3-545a-4e08-8af4-7fa6bd88bc6b1 where tha last digit in series in the int value

Comment: Yes. You can try the update I gave above in my answer.

Comment: can you update your answer with controller i didnt understant where to put that

Comment: now out of 11 images 6  is saving in the database . like guid0 ,guid2,guid4 upto guid10

Comment: Can you add try catch block inside for loop and add traces to see the filename and path is formed properly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148684/discussion-between-piyush-sanadhya-and-naresh-podishetty).

Comment: late reply but it worked just fine the updated method @naresh

Answer (score 2):

Well, I am not very familiar with HTML inputs, but I think you should use "multiple" attribute in you SINGLE file input tag.
Or rename "files" to "files[]".
Look at [this](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_multiple.asp)

Comment: well i'm not trying to upload multiple files from same uploader . The requirement is to save those images as guid followed by "i" or any string i want to concatenate.

Comment: @piyushsanadhya oh, ok. Are you sure your action is receiving all of the images you submit? I thought it may be only one passed. Can you watch files variable in the debugger?

Comment: all i files are being received at the controller i've checked with the debugging on

Comment: @piyushsanadhya what about ContentLength of each file? Did it even comes into IF block?

Comment: yes all is going well but its just the file name i can't get it right